# Google Cloud SQL mysql.user table is periodically wiped

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Since moving my project to Google Cloud SQL there have been two instances in 3 days where the myql.user table is apparently reset to its initial state. That is root password I set is removed and all of the non-root users I have added with GRANT commands are deleted from the table.

The first instance was when I converted the pricing plan from the per-use priceing plan to the package pricing plan.

The second instance was a few hours ago at about 2014-06-02 03:06:00 UTC. There was no activity from me or my application on the server when the second instance occured. It is possible that it was kicked off by the google automated backup process but I'm not sure the exact time that that occurs.

In both instances I had to reset the root password through the console to get command line access and then re-add the application users with GRANT commands.

I have not seen reports of anyone else experiencing this issue so I believe that it could be related to the fact that I am using the new character_set_server flag set to utf8mb4. This feature was released by google last week and is required by my app so store 4byte unicode characters.

I have reported the bug to google at https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=90 but have not gotten any response there yet.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? I am going to have to move my project off of Google cloud if I can't trust the data store and I'd really rather keep it there if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to make sure you are running [FLUSH PRIVILEGES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) after running your GRANTs? MySQL caches the privileges in memory, so if you don't flush them to disk and your database spins down uncleanly for some reason, MySQL might not write them out.

If this doesn't work, please contact us at cloud-sql@google.com with your instance name so we can look into it further for you.

Comment: I will run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and `FLUSH TABLES` immediately just to be sure. **However**, the issue is also affecting the root password set via the google web console and one difference between using GRANT and using an INSERT into the mysql.user table is that with a GRANT you are not supposed to have to run the FLUSH PRIVILEGES command.

Comment: With those two points in mind I do not believe this is the solution, or if it is a workaround there is still a bug in Cloud Sql that is causing the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you run a `FLUSH TABLES` after you make changes to the mysql.user table? What you are observing was probably caused by some data that the mysqld did not flush before the process was killed.

A related issue: [MySQL SPs and Events being automatically rolled-back by Google Cloud SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930802)

Comment: I will run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and `FLUSH TABLES` immediately just to be sure. **However**, the issue is also affecting the root password set via the google web console and one difference between using GRANT and using an INSERT into the mysql.user table is that with a GRANT you are not supposed to have to run the FLUSH PRIVILEGES command.

With those two points in mind I do not believe this is the solution, or if it is a workaround there is still a bug in Cloud Sql that is causing the issue in the first place.

Comment: The `FLUSH TABLES` is the one you really want. When you do that the table files are closed and reopen that that will cause all the data to be flushed and made persistent. We are going add a `FLUSH TABLES` before stopping to make things more resilient. :-)